# Hot to test ruby script with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

How to run/test ruby script in RSpec tests?

A simple example of a testing argument of called script

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

begin
  raise Errors::NoArgumentError                 if ARGV.count.zero?
rescue Errors => e
  puts e.message
  abort
end

file  = File.open(ARGV[0], 'r')
# Do something with file...
```

I tried to test with:

```
  it 'should throw no argument error' do
    expect {
     load('bin/script.rb') # Or system()
    }.to raise_error(Errors::NoArgumentError)
  end
```

Comment: `system` would not make sense in this scenario anyway. The wording of your example (argument to `it`) contradicts what you are doing in the `expect`. Also, I don't quite understand what you want to do. Define - in particular in this context - what you mean by _running a script_. BTW, with `load`, you can't pass arguments to `ARGV` anyway. You could do this with `system`, but then of course RSpec has no knowledge about the thrown exception anymore, because `system` runs the whole thing in a child process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to split the script and the application code into two different files which will make it a lot easier to test because you don't need to load the file and can easily inject arguments.

```rb
# script.rb
exit(Cli.run(ARGV)
```

and then have a `Cli` class which you can call

```rb
# cli.rb
class Cli
  def self.run(args)
    new(args).run
  end

  def initialize(args)
    @args = args
  end

  def run
    raise Errors::NoArgumentError if @args.count.zero?
    File.open(@args[0], 'r')
    0 # exit code
  rescue Errors => e
    puts e.message
    1 # exit code
  end
end
```

And then you can easily test this like

```rb
it 'should throw no argument error with no args provided' do
  expect {
    Cli.run([])
  }.to raise_error(Errors::NoArgumentError)
end

it 'should throw X if file does not exist' do
  expect {
    Cli.run(["not_existent"])
  }.to raise_error(Errors::NoArgumentError)
end
```

Comment: That changed my perspective! Did you mean new(args).call in self.run?

Comment: That's right. Updated!

Comment: Maybe just class method call/run would be enough. We are creating objects but without any need. What do you think Christian?

Comment: It depends how much more logic is in your method. Abstracting it in an object will make it a lot easier to refactor and split into helper functions instead of having one big class method.